# How to avoid php notices on undefined array indexes or type mismatch (null)? or simpli do a very easy check?

Tags: php

Take this:

```
$request_data['compiler_name'] = $data['compiler']['name'];
$request_data['compiler_company'] = $data['compiler']['company'];
$request_data['compiler_email'] = $data['compiler']['email'];
$request_data['compiler_city'] = $data['compiler']['city'];
$request_data['compiler_zip'] = $data['compiler']['zip'];
$request_data['compiler_country'] = $data['compiler']['country'];
$request_data['compiler_phone'] = $data['compiler']['phone'];
$request_data['compiler_function'] = $data['compiler']['function'];
```

Say I've got over 50 fields like those (they come from a big form). Not all fields are mandatory in the form, thus some could simply be undefined, cause the user maybe does not fill them.
Php keeps noticing me (filling the log file) with messages like: `Trying to access array offset on value of type null [...]` or `Undefined index: phone in [...]`, and it's right, but turns out I don't want those kind of notices for this particular program, and at the same time, I don't want to suppress all php notices.

How to stop them? Or, is there a better way than adding a ternary operator to check of index existence on each and every line above?

Comment: you have to check each value, ultimately.

Comment: Please share more details. Why not check for empty fields before reading from then?

Comment: Because it's too messy for my eyes with 50+ fields. And annoying. :) Should be something smarter. Php8 has the null-safe operator but only works on objects I think.

Comment: I'd take the time to create a more readable way of doing this, some sort of loop. Then it's not that bad to add a regular check if it's exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [short ternary operator](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php#shorthand-ternary-operator) or [null coalescing operator](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php#null-coalescing-operator) for that:

```
$data['compiler'] ??= [];

$fields = ['name', 'phone', /* ... */];

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $request_data["compiler_{$field}"] = $data['compiler'][$field] ?? null;
}
```

---

Or other structure

```
$request_data = [
    'compiler_name' => null,
    'compiler_phone' => null,
    /* ... */
];

foreach ($data['compiler'] as $key => $value) {
    $request_data["compiler_{$key}"] = $value;
}
```